# Communicating with a MW-3170 magnetic card reader

Tags: serial-port, point-of-sale, magnetic-cards

One of our customers has asked if we can interface with a serial magnetic card reader/encoder from a old EPOS system.  The device has no make only the [MW-3170](http://www.officezone.com/mw3000.htm) model number.

Does anybody know how I can communicate with the device?  I am currently looking for a programming manual on Google, without much success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reads cards conforming to these standards [ANSI 3554, ISO 7811/3](http://www.cyberd.co.uk/support/technotes/isocards.htm) and is likely a [serial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port) device with a [DB-9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature) connector judging by its age. Why don't you just call one of the vendors and ask for more information?

EDIT: It looks like I was right about the [interface](http://championsystems.net/magnetencdr.htm):

```
COMMUNICATIONS
Transmission Type  : Asynchronous
Interface          : RS232C
Baud Rate          : 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600 BPS
Data Length        : 7 bits or 8 bits
Parity             : Space, Odd, Even, Mark
Start Bit          : 1 bit
Stop Bit           : 1 bit
```

I'd further guess that it is probably an ASCII interface that would be easy to reverse-engineer even if you can't obtain documentation. Even if it is binary you can likely figure it out as long as you have magnetic cards containing known data.

Comment: Thanks, I've found some software on one of the manufacturers websites.  So I'll ask the customer if he still wants me to reverse-engineer the code.

Answer (score 0):

After further searching, I found programming software for the MW-3000 series card readers/writers on [Partner Tech USA](http://www.partner.com.tw/support/default.asp?dl=MW-3000).

Using a [serial port monitoring software](http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/), you can reverse-engineer the commands sent to the card reader.

To read from the card reader, send the following command.

```
<STX>R7<ETX> 
Hex: 02 52 37 03
```